# Shared preferences not picking the value in the next Activity

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I have a SharedPreference being setup like this, when I'm saving the user to Firebase. When the user is saved to Firebase, I set the name and email from the Profile object. I have 2 types of uses(Stand and Guard) who sign up to the application.

First page is the email and password which is common for both the user. Second page is getting the contact details which is also common, but I register guard user in this page. The last page is exclusive for Standard, where I register the Stand user to the application.

I set the sharedPreferences in the both the pages when I sign up the user. The sharedPreferences works fine when I register the Stand user, but when I register the Guard user, it doesn't pick up the preferences. Please find below what I have tried.

**GuardUserReg.java**

```
databaseReference.child("phoneNumber").setValue(phoneNumber);
databaseReference.child("dateOfBirth").setValue(dateOfBirth);
databaseReference.child("userType").setValue(userType);


databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Profile profile = dataSnapshot.getValue(Profile.class);
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ContactDetailsActivity.this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        if(profile != null) {
            editor.putString(Preferences.NAME, profile.getFullName());
            editor.putString(Preferences.EMAIL, profile.getEmail());
            editor.putString(Preferences.USER_TYPE, profile.getUserType());
        }
        editor.putString(Preferences.USERID, getUid());
        editor.apply();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

**StandUserReg.java**

```
databaseReference.child("phoneNumber").setValue(phoneNumber);
databaseReference.child("dateOfBirth").setValue(dateOfBirth);
databaseReference.child("guardianEmail").setValue(guardianUserEmail);
databaseReference.child("userType").setValue(userType);


databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Profile profile = dataSnapshot . getValue (Profile.class);
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager . getDefaultSharedPreferences (AddGuardianActivity.this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences . edit ();
        if (profile != null) {
            editor.putString(Preferences.NAME, profile.getFullName());
            editor.putString(Preferences.EMAIL, profile.getEmail());
            editor.putString(Preferences.USER_TYPE, profile.getUserType());
        }
        editor.putString(Preferences.USERID, getUid());
        editor.apply();
    }
```

This is the MainScreen, where I refer the Shared Preferences. Both the users are directed to the same screen, but they see different components.

**MainScreen.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainMenuActivity.this);
    final String userType = preferences.getString(Preferences.USER_TYPE, "");

    gaFragmentStack = new Stack<>();

    if(userType.equalsIgnoreCase("Standard")) {
        Fragment home_fragment = new HomeFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container_gaFragments, home_fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }else{
        Fragment home_guardian_fragment = new HomeGuardianFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container_gaFragments, home_guardian_fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
String name = preferences.getString(Preferences.NAME, "");
String email = preferences.getString(Preferences.EMAIL, "");
```

For the guardUser, this name and email always takes the default values, but for standUser registration, the values are working fine.

I am not able to find out what is the bug! Can anyone help?

Comment: `Toast.makeText(this, userType , 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` after this line(`final String userType = preferences.getString(Preferences.USER_TYPE, "");
`) and check.

Comment: The userType says "". It doesn't get any value for userType. But I have set it in the preferences using the editor and I don't know why its not working

Answer (score 0):

Change code in `StandUserReg.java`

```
    if(profile != null) {
        editor.putString(Preferences.NAME, profile.getFullName());
        editor.putString(Preferences.EMAIL, profile.getEmail());
        editor.putString(Preferences.USER_TYPE, "Standard");
    }
```

Change code in `GuardUserReg.java`

```
    if(profile != null) {
        editor.putString(Preferences.NAME, profile.getFullName());
        editor.putString(Preferences.EMAIL, profile.getEmail());
        editor.putString(Preferences.USER_TYPE, "Guard");
    }
```

Try again.

Comment: I did use the second option, throughout the Activities im using Shared Preferences, but still the values doesnt show up :(